# LinkButton not sending the correct CommandArgument to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I have a `GridView` with a `LinkButton`. The `GridView` has some files which are being pulled from a directory and displayed to the end users. Each file has its own description to go with it. Each of the file also has a download button which if clicked the file will download. I am passing the `CommandArgument` as follows

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName") %>'
```

The problem is when I click on the download button I get an error `Could not find file`. The path should be `C:\\Documents\\Test\\someFile.pdf` instead I get the path as `C:\\Documents\\someFile.pdf`

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

The rest of the code is below

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileDescription" HeaderText="Description" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" Font-Bold="true" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Test/"));
            List<FileDetails> files = new List<FileDetails>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                files.Add(new FileDetails()
                {
                    FileName = filename,
                    FileDescription = "This is a test file"
                });
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();

protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
```

My `FileDetails` class has two properties of `get` and `set`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using

```
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

for each file you want to add.

What happens is that you're adding "something.pdf" to the list.

What will happen when you click on the download button is that it will try and get the "something.pdf" from the relative path. Which in this case is without the "/test/" folder.

What you can do is to change the following code

```
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new FileDetails()
            {
                FileName = filename,
                FileDescription = "This is a test file"
            });
```

into

```
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            files.Add(new FileDetails()
            {
                FileName = filename,
                FullPath = filePath,
                FileDescription = "This is a test file"
            });
```

then add

```
 public string FullPath {get;set;}
```

inside your FileDetails class.

Finally, update your aspx so your command looks like

```
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("FullPath") %>'
```

Voila!

It should now work :-)